# How to make Puppet agent behaviour depend on other machines status?

Tags: puppet

I've googled this and searched for answers here but either cannot find it or I'm making this too complicated in my head.

This is the situation: There are two machines, A and B. Both of them install a binary.
Machine A will have to run a script once the binary is installed on machine B, not before.
This is the first step but all other steps are similar, there is a dependency on the other machine.

I can't seem to find a way to do this in puppet. Can someone put me on the right track please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing an orchestration problem, and Puppet itself is not intended or built for such problems.  Puppet, Inc. offers an Orchestrator product bundled with the professional edition of the software, and that would be your best bet if it is available to you.  Alternatively, previous versions of Puppet used MCollective, which should be available to you even if you're using open-source Puppet.

If there were just one such interaction between the machines in question then it might make sense to hack together some orchestration with Puppet itself -- it is possible. But you seem to be saying that you have multiple points where the two machines need to synchronize, and I really can't recommend trying to build that out with Puppet.  If you could, say, fully configure machine B before configuring A, so that there is only one synchronization point, then that might be a different story.